# Detectar evento de select generados dinamicamente con estilos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola mi problema es que no consigo detectar eventos de combobox generados dinámicamente ya que como son con estilos lo que se clickea en la vista es el select en si muestro como se ven
[image: como se ven en el jsp]

Cuando le doy en examinar se muestra así el código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asi los voy generando

```
b = 0;
function agregar() {
    b++;
    var divCantidad = document.createElement('div');
    var divCodigo = document.createElement('div');
    var divDescripcion = document.createElement('div');
    divCodigo.setAttribute('class', 'chosen-select-act fm-cmp-mg');
    divDescripcion.setAttribute('class', 'chosen-select-act fm-cmp-mg');
    divCantidad.setAttribute('class', 'nk-int-st');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:9090/sigicim/api/productoPedido',
        success: function (respuesta) {
            var codigos = "<option value=" + 0 + ">Elige un codigo</option>";
            var descripcion = "<option value=" + 0 + ">Elige un producto</option>";

            $.each(respuesta, function (key, registro) {
                codigos += "<option value=" + registro.codigoProducto + ">" + registro.codigoProducto + "</option>";
                descripcion += "<option>" + registro.descripcionProducto + "</option>";
            });
            divCantidad.innerHTML = '<input id="cantidad_' + a + '"type="number" class="form-control input-sm">';
            document.getElementById('canditadPedido').appendChild(divCantidad);

            divCodigo.innerHTML = '<select id="codigo_' + a + '" class="chosen" >' + codigos + '</select>';
            document.getElementById('codigosPedido').appendChild(divCodigo);
            divDescripcion.innerHTML = '<select id="descripcion_' + a + '" class="chosen" >' + descripcion + '</select>';
            document.getElementById('productosPedido').appendChild(divDescripcion);
            $(".chosen")[0] && $(".chosen").chosen({
                width: "100%",
                allow_single_deselect: !0
            });
            a++;
        }
    });
}
```

para intentar detectar los eventos ya intente

```
    $( () => {
  $('#tabla').on('click', 'select', function() {
    alert('Le diste click');
  });

});
```

Si me pudieran ayudar lo agradecería

Comment: es decir deseas detectar la opción seleccionada que generas dinamicamente ?

Comment: No es tanto la opción seleccionado si no saber el id del select que ha cambiado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debes añadir el evento en el select o las opciones, por ejemplo:

```
divDescripcion.innerHTML = '<select onChange="tufuncion(event);" id="descripcion_' + a + '" class="chosen" >' + descripcion + '</select>'
```

asi cuando se incluyen al DOM ya van con el evento

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder aunque precisamente esta evitando poner la función directamente, pero creo que lo voy a checar gracias

Comment: Me funciono y ya pude hacer lo que queria apartir de esto muchas gracias

Comment: Ecelente!, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Veo que estas usando un plugin jquery para poder dar formato al combo(select), eso hace que el combo(select) se oculte (display=none) y muestre el combo con diseño con un div#codigo_0_chosen.

En el código javascript el evento esta bien, pero esta atento a cualquier manipulación del div#tabla>combo(select) el cual esta oculto.

Podrias indicar el nombre del plugin que usas?, seguro tiene un evento para controlar el click.

---

Agrego un ejemplo para obtener los eventos, la información se encuentra en [el siguiente enlace](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html).

```js
$("#mi_select").chosen(); 

$('#mi_select').on('change', function(evt, params) {
    //do_something(evt, params);
    console.log("Seleccionado: " + params["selected"]);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." id="mi_select" tabindex="1">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="United States">United States</option>
  <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
  <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
  <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
  <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
  <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
  <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
  <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
  <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
  <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>

<script src="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/docsupport/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
```

---

Se agrega nueva implementación se detalla en el comentario.

```js
    $(".mi_combito").chosen(); 

    $('.mi_combito').on('change', function(evt, params) {
        //do_something(evt, params);
        //console.log(evt.target.id);
        console.log("Combobox: " + evt.target.id + ", con el valor: " + params["selected"]);
    });
```

```html
    <link href="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." id="mi_select_1" class="mi_combito" tabindex="1">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="United States">United States</option>
      <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
      <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
      <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
      <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
      <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
      <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
      <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
      <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
      <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
      <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
      <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
    </select>
    
    <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." id="mi_select_2" class="mi_combito" tabindex="1">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="United States">United States</option>
      <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
      <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
      <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
      <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
      <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
      <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
      <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
    </select>
    
    <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." id="mi_select_3" class="mi_combito" tabindex="1">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="United States">United States</option>
      <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
      <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
      <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
      <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
      <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
      <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
    </select>
    
    <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." id="mi_select_4" class="mi_combito" tabindex="1">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="United States">United States</option>
      <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
      <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
      <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
      <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
      <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
      <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
      <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
    </select>

    <script src="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/docsupport/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hola y muchas gracias por responder utilizo el plugin chosen https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ el problema que me surge cuando utilizo lo que dice en el apartado de Observing, Updating, and Destroying Chosen
es que si hago `$("#form_field").chosen().change( … );` me genera otro select vacio y no puedo agregar nada dinamicamente

Comment: Hola @EsmeraldaRodríguez, modifique y agrege un ejemplo, espero pueda ayudarte.

Comment: Muchas gracias me ayudaste entender la otra parte de la documentación, el problema es que para tu ejemplo ya debo saber el id y es precisamente lo quiero saber es decir, _quien cambio_ ya que si miras el jsp que subi hay dos entonces si en uno cambia el otro también, pero como se pueden agregar muchos.... no se si me explico bien pero realmente agradezco mucho tu ayuda

Comment: Disculpa por responder tan tardíamente, entonces, tal vez no entienda, pero deseas un ejemplo con dos comboboxs, y cuando alguno cambie, detectar cual cambio, y cual es el valor que se selecciono???

Comment: si es correcto, por eso necesitaba detectar los eventos pero como pueden ser n cantidad de comboboxs no te preocupes c: @Kamousagi